# Prove that the maximum number of edges in a graph with no even cycles is floor(3(n-1)/2)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

The question is in the title. I can see why the bound is sharp (for example, a lot of triangles sharing one common vertex if n is odd, or the same but with one spare edge hanging out if n is even). But I can't prove why the bound is the best possible.

I know that each edge must belong to at most one cycle. I was thinking that you could take any path or odd big odd cycle and turn it into bunch of triangles wherever possible, but I think that might not be valid because a lot of greedy local optimums isn't necessarily the global optimum. So what do I do?

I tried looking online for an answer before posting this and all I could find is this: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180306011341/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52261.html)
Is the reasoning faulty there? I couldn’t make sense of it after it talked about decomposing into cycles.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true if graph is not simple, for example take a single vertex and a loop, there is one edge, but your bound equals zero.

On the other hand, if the graph in question is simple then here are some hints:

- WLOG you can assume that your graph is a single connected component.
- Take some spanning tree of it, you will have $n-1$ edges there.
- You are left with more than $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$ edges, but observe that you cannot add any vertices (the spanning tree touches all of them), therefore, *any* edge you add will produce a cycle (at least one).
- No edge can be shared among cycles, as this would create an even cycle (this means that each edge you add will create a cycle, but it mustn't create two or more).
- The best you can do is form triangles (the smallest possible odd cycles), but you can't obtain more than $\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$ (for any of the remaining edges you need two from the spanning tree), which is why you can't add yet more edges.

I hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Like with my original post though, I'm not sure I'm happy with your last bullet point (even though I sort of know it's right). Why is it the case that doing the best we can do each time (making triangles) will turn out to be the best idea overall for the graph?

After that though, we can't obtain more than floor(n-1/2) triangles as each triangle uses uniquely 2 edges from the n-1 edges of the the tree, so we need a kind of 2:1 ratio, right? After that if we add another edge it will definitely join 2 cycles that are already connected, creating an even cycle?

Comment: @peter Read closely, it's in the bullet points. **Each** edge of the last $(n-1)/2$ creates a cycle, and **no** edge can be shared (that is each creates **one** cycle). Therefore, to add more edges you need to be able to add more cycles and thus you have to use the smallest possible of spanning tree's edges per cycle. The smallest you can get is two edges from the tree and one new. In other words, if no edges can be shared, all the cycles have to be independent and since you have to use at least 2 edges (per cycle) from the spanning tree, you cannot make more than $(n-1)/2$ cycles.

Comment: Thanks.
Okay that makes sense. It's ideal if those extra edges make triangles (whether or not you can make it happen isn't important, but that's the best case scenario . You can't do more than (n-1)/2 cycles because there's no tree left, right?

Why, when adding edges onto the spanning tree, do we need to use 2 edges from the spanning tree and one added edge to form a triangle? Why not use 1 edge from the spanning tree and add 2 edges to form a triangle? is it to do with WLOG?

Thanks for your help. Also, would you mind taking a look at the link I posted to check the proof?

Comment: Exactly, can't make more cycles, because there's not enough edges of the spanning tree. Adding two edges and taking one from the tree would create a new vertex (which you can't as stated previously). If you were to add two edges using vertices of the tree, each of those would create a cycle, so those can't form one cycle, otherwise an even cycle would be formed. Another formulation: each edge creates a cycle with a tree, that cycle consists of one new edge (the one you added) and some edges from the tree, but cycle length can't be smaller than 3,so you have to use at least 2 edges of the tree.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks as I was being quite slow!

Comment: @peter Let me know which part caused "it clicked" for you, so that I can update my answer.