# Graph Theory: How do we know Hamiltonian Path exists in graph where every vertex has degree ≥3?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I am trying to prove that if every node of a graph G has degree of at least 3 then G contains a cycle and a chord.  My current approach is as follows:

1. Separate the graph G into connected components and consider any component C.
2. ***There exists a (hamiltonian) path that includes all the vertices in C***.  Label these vertices $V_0$...$V_k$.
3. Consider $V_0$.  In addition to being connected to $V_1$, it must also be connected with two other vertices on the path, $V_i$ and $V_j$, where $i < j$.
4. We therefore have a cycle $\{V_0,V_1,V_2,...,V_i,...,V_j,V_0\}$.  We also have a chord (a connection between two points within a cycle) between $V_i$ and $V_0$.  Thus G contains both a cycle and a chord.

The part that I bolded and italicized is the part that's giving me trouble.  I don't see how I can know that there is necessarily a path that connects all the vertices in C.  And if such a path does not exist then I'm not sure how to get this proof to work.

**EDIT**

I thought of a possible solution but I want to confirm that it is valid:

1. Separate the graph G into connected components and consider any component C.
2. Consider a path of maximum length within C.  Label these vertices $V_0$...$V_k$.
3. We know that $V_0$ and $V_k$ cannot connect to vertices outside of the current path, because otherwise the current path would not be a maximal path.  Thus $V_0$ and $V_k$ must only be connected to vertices along the path.
4. Consider $V_0$.  In addition to being connected to $V_1$, it must also be connected with two other vertices on the path, $V_i$ and $V_j$, where $i < j$.
5. We therefore have a cycle $\{V_0,V_1,V_2,...,V_i,...,V_j,V_0\}$.  We also have a chord (a connection between two points within a cycle) between $V_i$ and $V_0$.  Thus G contains both a cycle and a chord.

Comment: It's simply not true that such a graph must have a Hamiltonian path. See [Euler's Königsberg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg), for instance.

Comment: @TonyK maybe I didn't get your example right, but if you mean the Konigsberg graph, then it definitely has a Hamiltonian path (even a Hamiltonian cycle).

Comment: @TonyK The Königsberg graph has no Eulerian path, but it does have a Hamiltonian path, in fact it has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: according to your edit it seems that it is enough for you to have a cycle with a chord in $G$ (not necessarily a cycle that contains ALL vertices in some connected component of $G$).

Comment: Your method might have problems because of [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4190) and [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3024). Also, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/454907/26306) answer.

Comment: @dtldarek In fact, I would bet that this question is a duplicate of your last [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454907/prove-that-if-every-node-in-a-simple-graph-g-has-degree-3-or-higher-then-g).

Comment: The proof in your edit is fine, so you don't need that false proposition about a Hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a connected $3$-regular graph with no Hamiltonian path. Let $H_1,H_2,H_3$ be three vertex-disjoint copies of $K_4$. For each $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ choose an edge $e_i$ of $H_i$ and subdivide it, making the midpoint of $e_i$ into a new vertex $x_i$. Finally, take a new vertex $y$ and add edges $x_1y,x_2y,x_3y$. This connected $3$-regular graph on $16$ vertices does not have a Hamiltonian path, because removing the vertex $y$ breaks it into three components.

Comment: Maybe check [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2993531/428188) below for a better illustration?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple graph for you:

> [image]

Comment: This graph (the Petersen graph) *does* have a Hamiltonian path, which is what OP is asking about. (It does not, however, admit a Hamiltonian cycle.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the claim is not true. Another example is the complete bipartite graph, $K_{3, 5}$ (see diagram below). In fact, my answer to a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317114/is-there-a-graph-with-all-vertices-having-degree-3-or-greater-that-doesnt-have/4317124#4317124https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317114/is-there-a-graph-with-all-vertices-having-degree-3-or-greater-that-doesnt-have/4317124#4317124) shows that $K_{3, 5}$ has the minimal number of vertices ($8$) among all graphs whose vertices all have degree $\geq 3$ but which admit no Hamiltonian paths.

[image]