# Is there a graph with all vertices having degree 3 or greater that doesn't have a hamiltonian path?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Is there an example of a simple, undirected graph with all vertices having degree 3 or greater that doesn't have a hamiltonian path? I've seen this question appear in the title of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565136/graph-theory-how-do-we-know-hamiltonian-path-exists-in-graph-where-every-vertex) post, but then the author proceeds to talk about cycles and chords rather than hamiltonian paths. I haven't been able to come up with any simple, undirected graphs where all the vertices are of degree 3 or greater and there doesn't exist a hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, even if we further restrict (as you probably had in mind) to connected graphs. One example is the complete bipartite graph $K_{3, 5}$, whose partitions have $3$ and $5$ vertices. (In fact, this is the smallest example; see below.)

More generally, since the sequence of vertices of any Hamiltonian path must alternate between the $2$ partitions, any bipartite graph wherein one partition has at least $2$ more vertices than the other admits no Hamiltonian path.

[image: bipartite graph K_{3, 5} of bi-order (3, 5)]

On the other hand, a theorem of [Rahman-Kaykobad](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S002001900400362X)---related to but strictly stronger than [Ore's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem)---states that (borrowing from Wikipedia):

> A [connected,] simple graph with $n$ vertices has a Hamiltonian path if, for every non-adjacent, [distinct] vertex pairs the sum of their degrees and their shortest path length is greater than $n$.

By definition the path length between any two distinct, nonadjacent vertices is $\geq 2$, and in our setting each degree is $\geq 3$, giving a sum of at least $3 + 3 + 2 = 8$ for each pair of vertices. So, the theorem implies that every graph with fewer than $8$ vertices but with all vertices having degree $\geq 3$ admits a Hamiltonian path. In particular $K_{3, 5}$ has the smallest vertex count of any example.

More generally, a graph whose vertices all have degree $\geq m$ but no Hamiltonian path must have at least $2 m + 2$ vertices, and the complete bipartite graph $K_{m, m + 2}$ furnishes a minimal example.

---

Comment: Isn't it enough that the number of vertices of the two partitions differ by one, like for $K_{3,4}$?

Comment: @BillyJoe the question is about a Hamiltonian path not a cycle.

Comment: @BillyJoe Joffan is right: If we were looking for a Hamiltonian cycle differing by one would suffice.

Comment: I can't see a Hamiltonian path in $K_{3,4}$.

Comment: @BillyJoe Start with any vertex in the partition with $4$ vertices, then choose an arbitrary unchosen edge until you have visited all $7$ vertices.