# Greatest number of edges in a graph which does not contain even cycles.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose we have graph with $n$ vertices and no simple cycles of even length. What is the greatest number of edges in such a graph?

Comment: I suppose you mean cycles?

Comment: Sorry, my bad..

Answer (score 0):

Such a (connected) graph you describe has minimal degree at most $2$ (because having minimal degree at least $3$ forces the graph to have a cycle of even length).

I came to the following upper bound: A graph with $n$ vertices such as in the OP has at most $2n$ edges. This is easily proven by induction (indeed it is trivially true for $n \leq 5$) using the fact (as written in the first paragraph) that such a graph has minimal degree at most $2$.

However the best upper bound is $\lfloor \frac{3(n-1)}{2} \rfloor$. See [Prove that the maximum number of edges in a graph with no even cycles is floor(3(n-1)/2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438853/prove-that-the-maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-graph-with-no-even-cycles-is-floor3?rq=1)